# How to create usage alarm using Cloudwatch for Service Quota when the Utilization is Not available in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail, cloudwatch-alarms, aws-service-quotas

I want to create alerts in aws to notify when the service quota utilization has crossed the threshold value for service quotas for which the Utilization field is disabled

I am trying to create Infrastructure quota monitoring alerts in aws , but for few service quotas I am unable to create it .

For example, `Internet gateways per Region` from `Amazon VPC` has utilization field disabled, no create alarm option available under it along with usage graph , and there is no metrics for that under CloudWatch All metrics then All->Usage->By AWS Resource , which is needed to create usage alarms .(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yjsZ.png)

What is the reason that some of the service quotas doesn't have the utilization details available? and how to create usage quota alarm for those?

Comment: posted a solution @rudin on creating alarms on cloudtrail which is integrated with service quotas.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but as I can see In [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) that service quotas is integrated with cloudtrail, so you can create a cloudwatch alarm on cloudtrail for that particular event quota logs.

> Create a filter based on the logs you see on cloudtrail and for cloudwatch alarms threshold value should be service quota threshold value.When your metric filter crosses the threshold value, you will recieve an alert.
> Ofcourse you would need to find the cloudtrail logs for that service quota in order to create filter pattern.

See [creating alarms for cloud trails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html)

Comment: according to cloudtrail it generates entries for `GetServiceQuota, RequestServiceQuotaIncrease and ListAWSDefaultServiceQuotas actions` , but I need a solution to track the usage of resources so that I can set alarm based on usage threshold . I created a lambda function to calculate the usage percentage and put that as a custom metric and then based on the custom metric I created the alarm . Anyway thanks for your answer @Jatin